# Ubuntu terminal automation

Tags: automation, zsh

Is there a way to run a script by opening a new window and sending inputs to it, so that is looks like someone is typing into the window?

Comment: Either `expect - Automates interactive applications`, or it's an XY problem. What are you trying to end up with?

Comment: I am trying to to record a terminal session using [asciinema](https://asciinema.org)- but instead of typing each command, I want to automate it.

Comment: Then I recommend `script` and `scriptreplay`, part of the `bsdutils` package.

Answer (score 1):

First determine the TTY used in the console you want to write to:

```
#tty
 /dev/pts/3
```

Then use that device and write to it using IO redirection:

```
#echo -n "text" > /dev/pts/3
```

The -n is to make echo not produce a new line.
You can send one character at a time to make it look like typing.

You can also do this inside terminal multiplexers like tmux or screen. Generally those are used for this application since they manage a tty and can detach from it.

Comment: I also want to execute the command afterwards.

Comment: Welp you may wanna update your question XD My answer will not do that at all because its entirely visual. It doesn't actually get interpreted by bash at all.